# MBP doesn't recognize thunderbolt 3 dock anymore

Tags: big-sur, thunderbolt, dock

Some days ago my MBP(2018, Big Sur 11.5.1) suddenly stopped working with my Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Dock. Until that event both worked together perfectly. Now it can still charge but won't detect any peripherals. I kept googling for hours now but I can't find a solution for my problem. My first thought was "the dock is dead." But it still works with my Thinkpad T480s without any problem. The dock's firmware is up-to-date. I tried using a different tb3 cable and resetting the SMC. Nothing helped.

Two strange things I noticed: When the dock is connected then dmesg gets spammed with

```
[ 5091.252376]: 3364379587us IOThunderboltSwitch(0@0)::processPlugEvent - Thunderbolt HPD packet for rid = 0 route = 0x0 port = 1 plug = 1
[ 5091.252386]: 3364379587us IOThunderboltSwitch(0@0)::processPlugEvent - Thunderbolt HPD packet for rid = 0 route = 0x0 port = 1 plug = 1
[ 5091.273085]: 3364400296us IOThunderboltSwitch(0@0)::processPlugEvent - Thunderbolt HPD packet for rid = 0 route = 0x0 port = 1 plug = 0
[ 5091.273097]: 3364400296us IOThunderboltSwitch(0@0)::processPlugEvent - Thunderbolt HPD packet for rid = 0 route = 0x0 port = 1 plug = 0
```

and

```
[ 1443.321284]: IOThunderboltSwitchType3(0x1)::readEEPROMInternal - No DROM found. Using default Type 2.1 DROM.
```

The second thing:

I can't boot the mbp with the dock connected. It gets stuck at the apple logo until I unplug the Dock.

Does anyone have an idea how I can find out what's wrong? Or how I can find out if my macbooks thunderbolt hardware is fried without buying a new dock to test?